# Error charset when backup xampp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using XAMPP as my webserver on my local computer.

Today i need to upgrade my XAMPP to a newer version at **1.7.2.** So i backup the htdocs folder and the **mysql/data** folder.
After installing a new version of XAMPP, I copy all the backup folders to their old destinations.
But when i run one of my websites, it seems to be an error with the charset. But all of the databases has a collation of **utf8_unicode_ci** as it was.

Could you help me to correct this?

And could you tell me what is the right way to back up my websites when I need to upgrade XAMPP?

Thank you